# Cassandra cluster : How it resolve single timestamp updates?

Tags: cassandra

In Cassandra cluster say I have twp nodes, Now clients send update for the same record(with different values) exactly at same time which goes to
two different nodes of Cassandra cluster. As Cassandra works in master less mode and both nodes can take the update request, 
My question is how this conflict will be resolved during eventual consistency and which value will ultimately take precedence ?

Here is the example scenario

```
Initial data: KeyA: { colA:"val AA", colB:"val BB"}

Client 1 sends update:  `update data set colA:"val C1_ColA" where 
colB="val BB"` and data becomes below at node_1

KeyA: { colA:"val C1_ColA",  colB:"val BB"}

Client 2 `update data set colA:"val C2_ColA" where 
colB="val BB"` and data becomes becomes below at node_2

KeyA: { colA:"val C2_ColA",  colB:"val BB"}
```

Now how the value of `colA` will eventually be resolved here ?

Answer (score 2):

**last write always wins**, and I doubt that the timestamps will be the same - they are with microseconds resolution, so it's very low probability that timestamp will have the same value.

If you want to prevent this situation, then you can use [lightweight transactions](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useInsertLWT.html) that allow to put condition on insert/updates/deletes, but you need to keep in mind that they are very resource intensive, and will add quite big load to the cluster.

Comment: I understand probability probability is very low but when you design you can not skip even those rare scenarios . For example in very scalable system with multinodes there is possibility where updates happen at same time on same record.

Comment: Also not sure how the scenario I mentioned will be resolved with with  lightweight transactions link you mentioned ?

Comment: You can set condition on what value should be there already before updating

Comment: You can set the condition and verify the value on single node but how will you do it in multi nodes.

Comment: sorry - I don't understand the problem - LWT is executed in cluster, like `QUORUM` (`SERIAL`), or `LOCAL_QUORUM` (`LOCAL_SERIAL`) - if value in condition is different, transaction will be aborted...